# Why 4.1%2 returns 0.0999999999999996 using Ruby?But 4.2%2==0.2

Tags: ruby, floating-accuracy

Why 4.1%2 returns 0.0999999999999996?But 4.2%2==0.2.

Comment: for me `4.2 % 2 == 0.20000000000000018` (ruby 1.9.2)

Comment: You can find easier analysis here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136860/how-to-check-dependencies-of-floats/9136907#9136907

Answer (score 5):

See here: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Real numbers are infinite. Computers are working with a finite number of bits (32 bits, 64 bits today). As a result floating-point arithmetic done by computers cannot represent all the real numbers. 0.1 is one of these numbers.

Note that is not an issue related to Ruby, but to all programming languages because it comes from the way computers represent real numbers.

Comment: This paper frequently gets cited in answers to questions like this, but it's really not aimed at beginners.

Comment: I agree but I don't know an other easier document on the subject. Do you ?

Comment: See my answer elsewhere on this question.

Comment: Factually,it is really hard for me(a beginner) to understand the paper.But at least I already know why it happens.Thank you for your help.

Comment: I agree but don't worry I think the first pages are enough to clearly answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

`Float`s can not always be represented exactly, see

[What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: This paper frequently gets cited in answers to questions like this, but it's really not aimed at beginners.

Comment: Yes, but I'd rather leave it to OP to decide if the paper is good for him or not instead of deciding that for him.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different page about floating-point: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html.  It's from the Python docs, but it's true of all languages that use fixed-size binary floats.

Answer (score 1):

In double-precision, 4.1 = 4.0999999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375 and 4.2 = 4.20000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125. In other words, the binary approximation to decimal 4.1 is slightly less than you'd expect, and the binary approximation to decimal 4.2 is slightly more.

Now why did 0.20000000000000017... round to 0.2 but 0.099999999999999644... NOT round to 0.1? Ruby is probably rounding all output to 15 significant decimal digits.

Comment: Although @32bitkid's Ruby (from comment above) seems to round to 17 digits. What version of Ruby are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Because you're working in floating-point.  Binary floating-point cannot represent 0.1 exactly.