# Precision of decimal number in Java, C, C++ and others

Tags: java, c++, c, decimal, decimal-point

Let's say we have this kind of loop (pseudocode)

```
double d = 0.0
for i in 1..10 {
    d = d + 0.1
    print(d)
}
```

In C with `printf("%f", d)` I get this:

```
0.100000
0.200000
0.300000
...
1.000000
```

In C++ with `cout << d` I get this:

```
0.1
0.2
...
1
```

In Java with `System.out.println(d)` I get this:

```
0.1
0.2
0.3 (in debug mode, I see 0.30000000000004 there but it prints 0.3)
...
0.7
0.799999999999999
0.899999999999999
0.999999999999999
```

So my questions are these:

1. Why is this simple code printed in Java so badly and is correct in C?
2. How does this behave in other languages?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

Comment: These are not decimal numbers, they are binary.  Learn this well.

Comment: StackOverflow needs a bayesian filter which automatically looks for the words 'Decimal' and 'Precision' in new posts...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is this simple code printed in Java so badly and is correct in C?

Since you are not comparing the same operations, you will get different result.

The behaviour of `double` is exactly the same across different languages as it uses the hardware to perform these operations in each case.  The only difference is the methods you have chosen to display the result.

In Java, if you run

```
double d = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    System.out.printf("%f%n", d += 0.1);
```

it prints

```
0.100000
0.200000
0.300000
0.400000
0.500000
0.600000
0.700000
0.800000
0.900000
1.000000
```

---

If you run

```
double d = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) d += 0.1;
System.out.println("Summing 0.1, 8 times " + new BigDecimal(d));
System.out.println("How 0.8 is represented " + new BigDecimal(0.8));
```

you get

```
Summing 0.1, 8 times 0.79999999999999993338661852249060757458209991455078125
How 0.8 is represented 0.8000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125
```

Comment: Does it mean that in every language the double value 0.8 is stored as 0.79999999999999? Because this __ugly__ value I can see in debug mode in the variable view.

Comment: @Tomas: the way you compute `.8` yield `.79999999999999993339`, but if you just enter the literal, you'll get `.80000000000000004441`.

Comment: No, the value of 0.8 is not exact, but the sum or 0.1 + 0.1 + ... 0.1 is slightly less than the representation for 0.8. See my edit.

Comment: And what happens if I try to compute with precision on 20 decimal places? Will it be exact with BigDecimal or not?

Comment: With BigDecimal, its as accurate as you specify.  It also supports different round strategies.  This is why its a popular choice when dealing with money.

Comment: If you construct a `BigDecimal` using the `new BigDecimal(double)` constructor, it will have the exactly same value as the passed `double`, that means that `new BigDecimal(0.1)` will have the "wrong" value. Use the `new BigDecimal(String)` constructor instead, it's value will be precise, i.e. the value of `new BigDecimal("0.1")` will be precisely 0.1.

Comment: Technically the behaviour may not be _exactly_ the same in each language. Certain libraries, compilers, and compiler options, allow modification of the floating point mode on the CPU as well as specifying truncation flags. It is therefore possible that equivalent code in two languages may yield different results.

Comment: @natix In this case using `new BigDecimal(double)` is the right answer because I want to show the exact represented value without any rounding in the conversion to a String. `new BigDecimal(String)` wouldn't show this and is only useful if you have a String in the first place.  Another option to minimise rounding error is to use `BigDecimal.valueOf(double)`

Comment: @Peter Lawrey I agree, I was just pointing this out for Tomas.

Answer (score 7):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788640/why-4-12-returns-0-0999999999999996-using-rubybut-4-22-0-2/8788659#8788659), this is not related to any language.

See here: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Real numbers are infinite. Computers are working with a finite number of bits (32 bits, 64 bits today). As a result floating-point arithmetic done by computers cannot represent all the real numbers. 0.1 is one of these numbers.

Note that is not an issue related to Ruby, but to all programming languages because it comes from the way computers represent real numbers.

Answer (score 2):

1. Because of the way the print routines behave. `0.1` cannot be exactly represented in a binary floating point format.
2. In Python:

   ```
   >>> print('%.20f' % (.1 * 8))
   0.80000000000000004441
   >>> d = .0
   >>> for i in xrange(10):
   ...  d += .1
   ...  print('%.20f' % d)
   ... 
   0.10000000000000000555
   0.20000000000000001110
   0.30000000000000004441
   0.40000000000000002220
   0.50000000000000000000
   0.59999999999999997780
   0.69999999999999995559
   0.79999999999999993339
   0.89999999999999991118
   0.99999999999999988898
   ```

   But note:

   ```
   >>> print('%.20f' % .8)
   0.80000000000000004441
   ```