# Floating point accuracy in Clojure

Tags: clojure, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I am trying to learn Clojure and tried defining this simple function:

```
user=> (defn triple [arg] (* 3 arg))
#'user/triple
user=> (triple 1)
3
user=> (triple 1.01)
3.0300000000000002
```

Can anyone explain why there is a 2 at the end of the result here?

Comment: You could read some analysis on the problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136860/how-to-check-dependencies-of-floats/9136907#9136907

Comment: Note that this is not a clojure-specific issue, but one of how computers handle arithmetic in general.

Answer (score 12):

Due to the representation of floating point numbers on computers, operations on these numbers are not precise. It applies both to JVM and physical machines. See [Floating point inaccuracy examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples) for a longer discussion. There's also a comprehensive article [*What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) linked in the answers to that question.

Answer (score 6):

It's due to [floating point inaccuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples), which affects all languages with floating point representations. There are some values that cannot be accurately represented with floating point numbers.

Fortunately, Clojure also has support for high precision numerics, so you can do:

```
(defn triple [arg] (* 3 arg))
(triple 1.01M)
=> 3.03M
```

Note the use of "M" at the end of numeric constants to indicate that you want to use high precision numbers. In this case [java.math.BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) numbers are used by Clojure under the hood.

Comment: In fact, when you use the M notation, you get not just high precision but arbitrary precision.  It isn't just a matter of jumping from 32 bits to 64 bits.

Comment: Just for completeness, it also works with ratios e.g.  (triple (/ 101 100))  =>303/100